# Close the border of a polyhedron

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I have a polyhedron which has one face missing. I have a library function which can help close the border after sending in an array of points in CCW order:

```
class Mesh {
  // points need to be in CCW order when see from the ouside of this polyhedron
  void addAFace(std::vector<Point> points); 
}
```

I have found the vertices on the border and have put them in an array one after the other. How can I know if the order of vertices in this array is in counter-clockwise or clockwise order when seeing from the outside of the polyhedron?

For example, the vertices should be in the order of 0, 1, 2, 3

[image]

---

The polyhedron may be non-convex.

Comment: Is your polyhedron convex?

Answer (score 0):

For convex polyhedron: get any point Px in polyhedron not belonging to that face (for example, vertex 4, 5, 6 or 7 for your example) and check sign of triple product - should be negative for CCW order

```
 ((P1 - P0) .cross. (P2 - P1)) .dot. (Px - P1)
```

If there is no guarantee that P0-P3 are properly ordered, then it is needed to check signs of triple products for all face vertices triplets

If polygon is concave, you need some point near given face but lying inside polyhedron. For example, choose any triplet of consequent vertices with acute internal angle, get center of triangle and shift this center along normal by small distance. Check that shifted point is inside, make reflection otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, in my case there is a chance to be non-convex.

Comment: I added some thoughts for non-convex ones.